# Serilog LoggerConfiguration equivalent of AddFilter with log level

Tags: serilog

My current code is like this:

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) 
{
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => {
          logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR", LogLevel.Debug);
          logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections", LogLevel.Debug);
      })
      .UseSerilog(Log.Logger)
}
```

I now get deprication error:

> warning CS0618: 'SerilogWebHostBuilderExtensions.UseSerilog(IWebHostBuilder, ILogger, bool, LoggerProviderCollection)' is obsolete: 'Prefer UseSerilog() on IHostBuilder'

My understanding is I need to now create the logger like this:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    // set filters ???
    .CreateLogger();
```

and then just have `UseSerilog()` in `CreateWebHostBuilder`

But how do I set equivalent filters in `LoggerConfiguration` ? I can't seem to find relevant  examples.

Comment: Which version of .NET Core are you on?

Comment: .NET 7 ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is telling you to move away from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder` to `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostBuilder`.

`IWebHostBuilder` is for .NET Core 2, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#hostbuilder-replaces-webhostbuilder).

Your code would look like below.
*(Also renamed that method.)*

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => {
          logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR", LogLevel.Debug);
          logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections", LogLevel.Debug);
    })
    .UseSerilog(Log.Logger);
}
```

If you can't migrate, you'll have to pick an older version of `Serilog`.

Comment: I realized I need AddFilter on `builder.Host.UseSerilog` .. I posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71374831/serilog-builder-host-and-addfilter